# Django template not receiving context data

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am unable to access the `user` context data for my view in the associated template file.

views.py

```
            def userprofile(request,username):
                user=User.objects.filter(username=username)
                if user:
                    user=user[0]
                    profile=Profile.objects.get(user=user)
                    post=getPost(user)
                    bio=profile.bio
                    conn=profile.connection
                    follower=profile.follower
                    following=profile.following
                    user_img=profile.userImage
                    print(user)
                    print(bio)
                    print(conn)
                    print(follower)
                    print(following)
                    print(user_img)
                    print(user)
                    data={

                    'user':user,
                    'bio':bio,
                    'conn':conn,
                    'follower':follower,
                    'following':following,
                    'userImg':user_img,
                    'posts':post

                    }



                    print(data)
                    return render(request,'userview/userProfile.html')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse(" 404   No Such User exist")
```

My data is printed in the console after `runserver`, so can you tell me why it is not accessible in the template file below.

profile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block title %}profile{% endblock title %} 
<style>
.pst{
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

</style>
{% block body %}
<div class="container my-4">
    <div class="media">
        <img src="{{userImg.url}}"class="align-self-start mr-3 userImage" alt=".......">
        <div class="media-body-info">
            <h4 class="mt-4" >{{user.get_username}}</h4>
            <p>Follower : {{follower}}   Following : {{followin}}     </p> 
            <p><b>{{bio}}</b></p>

        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
<!-- <h3> Username:{{user.get_username}}</h3>    
<h3> FirstName:{{user.first_name}}</h3>    
<h3> lastname:{{user.last_name}}</h3>    
<h3> Email:{{user.email}}</h3>     -->
<!-- <h3> country:{{user.country}}</h3> sss    -->


<div class="row">
    {% for i in posts %}

    {% for j in i %} 
    <div class="col-md--4 ">
        <img src="{{j.image.url}}" alt="" class="pst">
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}


</div>
</div>

{% endblock body %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the context data to your template. You need to change your `render` call to `return render(request,'userview/userProfile.html', data)`.

Also, make sure the path to your template file is correct.

I would take a look at Django [Getting Started guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/) as your code could generally be tidied up a bit.